# MVC 5 populate dropdown list from another table and save value NOT KEY

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem is very simple. I would like to populate DropDownList with values from another table. But I don't want to link them with foreigin key.

My model

```
 public class Application1
 {
    public int Application1Id { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationType { get; set; }
 }
```

field `ApplicationType` is the one that should keep the name of `ApplicationType` (from other table)

My Controller :

// GET: Application1/Create

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AppDataApplicationType = new SelectList(db.AppDataApplicationTypes, "AppDataApplicationTypeId", "Name");
    return View();
}

// POST: Application1/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Application1 application1)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Application1.Add(application1); 
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.AppDataApplicationTypeId = new SelectList(db.AppDataApplicationTypes, "AppDataApplicationTypeId", "Name");     
    return View();
}
```

And my view :

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <span class="glyphicon-asterisk" style="color:red;"></span>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationType , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label", style="margin-bottom:10px;" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ApplicationType, (SelectList) ViewBag.AppDataApplicationType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to save this everything is ok but it's saving id instead of value.

I'll be very appreciate for any help, spend hours for trying solve it ...

Comment: why you want to save value instead of id?

Comment: if you want to save value then swap ``"AppDataApplicationTypeId", "Name"`` to ``" "Name",AppDataApplicationTypeId"`` in selectlist constructor or set both to ``Name``

Comment: the reason is very simple. In the future values (for dropdownlist) will change. I don't like them to disappear after they will be removed from database. So the connection is something I dont't like to do in this case. But from the other hand I would like to have possibility to change ApplicationTypes. That's why.

Comment: You meant do it in controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
ViewBag.AppDataApplicationType = new SelectList(db.AppDataApplicationTypes, "AppDataApplicationTypeId", "Name");
```

to

```
ViewBag.AppDataApplicationType = new SelectList(db.AppDataApplicationTypes, "Name", "Name");
```